# Log all links into a text file using selenium C#

Tags: c#, selenium, logging

I was successfully able to log all the links of a website into a text file using the  tags and `href` attribute. But the problem I am facing is that the text log file not only logs the links, it also logs some stupid values like `javascript : void()`. How do i ignore these values? 
I tried using the `Contains` property but was unsuccessful or may be i was doing it in a wrong way.

Please help me out on this one with a small snippet of code or any documentation that I can refer to. Thanks

```
        foreach (var links in WebDriver.FindElements(By.TagName("a")))
        {
            var url = links.GetAttribute("href");
            if (url.Contains("http") || url.Contains("57803"))
            {
                LinksLogFile.WriteLine(url);
            }
        }
        LinksLogFile.Close();
```

Comment: You can use regex to check if url has a valid format. Maybe someting like this: '^(http:\/\/www\.|https:\/\/www\.|http:\/\/|https:\/\/)?[a-z0-9]+([\-\.]{1}[a-z0-9]+)*\.[a-z]{2,5}(:[0-9]{1,5})?(\/.*)?$' [ https://www.regextester.com/93652 ]

Comment: I was able find success by using regex. But i wanted to know if there is any other better solution other than using regex.

Comment: Uri.IsWellFormedUriString(string uriString, UriKind uriKind) should also work